# Как правильно отфильтровать многоуровневый массив?

Tags: php

```
$data = [
  'products' => [
    '523' => ['id' => 1,
      'pass' => '45vy45y45',
      'title' => 'Mensy'],
    '528' => ['id' => 2,
      'pass' => 'ub45r6u4',
      'title' => 'Mensy2'],
    '530' => ['id' => 3,
      'pass' => '564eu65b',
      'title' => 'Mensy3'],
  ]
];

$data = array_filter($data, function(){});
// или через
$data = array_reduce($data, function(){});
```

Как получить только `title`?

```
$data = [
  'products' => [
     '523' => 'Mensy',
     '528' => 'Mensy2',
     '530' => 'Mensy3',
  ]
];
```

Comment: через array_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-нибудь так

```
$result =  ['products' => array_column($data['products'], 'title')];
```